# Handling validation errors in different controllers

Tags: php, validation, cakephp-2.0

I'm fairly new to cakephp, so I may just be setting things up wrong here.

I have created a simple blog with comments and posts (among other things).

I can add Comments while viewing a Post which submits back to the Comments controller (/controllers/comments/add).

The problem that I am running into is that when there are validation errors, it displays them in the /views/comments/add view, rather than the view where I was adding the comment /views/posts/view.

This has to be a pretty common thing to do I'd think, where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can ask the add method of the comments controller to render a different view:

```
$this->render('/Posts/view');
```

But then of course you'll need to make sure all the data that the 'Posts/view/' file needs is collected and set by the add method of the Comments controller.

Instead, what I would do is just make the comment form submit via AJAX (you know about AJAX?). That way, you can render the Comments/add view (or the appropriate part of it) without refreshing the rest of the page.

Of course, users with Javascript disabled will still have to go to a different page to correct their errors. But that shouldn't happen often, and you can always just redirect them back to the Posts page once they successfully submit their comment.

If you're new to CakePHP, and you're going to use AJAX, you'll probably want to use something like this somewhere:

```
if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {
    $this->render('/Elements/ajax_comment_form');
}
// If it's not AJAX it'll fall through and show the regular comment add.ctp view
```

Comment: Each comment form is currently loaded via ajax calls. Haven't seen where to make asynchronous posts yet but that's what I wanted to end up doing. Going to look into that as well as using $this->render (which is how I'm already rendering the views heh).